# Phonegap can't deploy to device

Tags: android, cordova

I have setup both my Android Tab connected USB to my PC, ran >adb devices and my device is listed accordingly. I have set enabled USB debugging on my Android Tab. So it seems everything is connected.

Now I tried through the commandline "phonegap build android" or "phonegap install android" or  "phonegap run android", all stated "successfully installed onto device" but my device doesn't even move an inch. Nothing happened, no prompt nothing. Anyone have any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: Does it run in the Android simulator? You can also check the app icon in the device and try to launch it manually.

Comment: i dont have simulator as i would like to use a real tab to see the results. theres no app icon or anything in my tab device

Comment: Are you following this guidelines to build app for Android using PhoneGap CLI.http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-line%20Interface\

Comment: Yes I went thru that and got it running successfully by scanning QR code on my device. But after I installed Android SDK and build locally, no more QR code, so I have to connect via USB to my device, but it just seems that it doesn't deploy from PC to my Android Tab.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to update your Android SDK and Google USB driver, that you can find under SDK manager. Here is the link which may help you.

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-cli/issues/131

Comment: Hi I just installed today fresh version. Both the SDK and Google USB driver

Comment: Which version of PhoneGap are you using? What is the Android version in your device?